# Concatenating or formatting JComboBox Year, Month, Day integer values to Date type

Tags: java, swing, date

I have put the year, month, day on separate `JComboBoxes` Month JComboBox has it's own `renderer` to display month names instead of `integer` value of month. Where month begins at `0 (0-January....11-December)`

So, my problem is how I can put the year, month, day together and assign it to a `Date` data type.

I tried concatenating year, month, day together to a `String` variable

```
int startYear = Integer.parseInt(jcmbFirstSemStartDateYear.getSelectedItem().toString() );
int startMonth = Integer.parseInt(jcmbFirstSemStartDateMonth.getSelectedItem().toString() );
int startDay = Integer.parseInt(jcmbFirstSemStartDateDay.getSelectedItem().toString() );

String startDate = startYear+"-"+startMonth+"-"+startDay; //not sure if this okay
Date completeStartDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDate);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,completeStartDate);

hasConflict(completeStartDate, completeEndDate); //method to check conflict
```

But when I printed the value of `completeStartDate`, it displayed the month of February as 01.

[image]

I'm worried that this might be read as January instead of February when I extract the month to check for conflicts.

```
    public static boolean hasConflict(Date aStartDate, Date aEndDate){
        boolean hasConflict = false;
        Calendar calStart = Calendar.getInstance();
        calStart.setTime(aStartDate);
        int startYear = calStart.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int startMonth = calStart.get(Calendar.MONTH); //extract month
        int startDay = calStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // ... if else conditions to compare startDate with endDate
        return hasConflict;
    }
```

Later on, I'll store these dates to `mysql` database.

Any thoughts or advice?

Thank you.

Comment: You could create a `String` representation and then parse it based on the format, or you could use [`LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-)

Answer (score 2):

If possible you should probably use [`LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-)

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
```

At a stretch you could create a `String` representation and parse it

```
String dateValue = startYear + "/" + startMonth + "/" + startDay;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date data = sdf.parse(dateValue);
```

But given the simplicity of `LocalDate`, I'd go for that ... besides, if you're using Java 8 and above, you shouldn't really be using `java.util.Date` where you can and even if you're not, I'd consider JodaTime over `java.util.Date` anyway

Comment: Agree completely. They say you should prefer the [ThreeTen-Backport of the Java SE 8 date-time classes to Java SE 6 and 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) over JodaTime, though. I would expect this to give you fuil compatibility if and when you change to Java 8 at a later time.